# Sympy evalf() on Integral of Dirac Function

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to evaluate the following integral with `sympy`:

[image]

Expected value: 8

I solved it with the `integrate()` in *Attempt 1* (see below), but why doesn't `evalf()` work in *Attempt 2*?

---

**Given**

```
import sympy as sp


sp.init_printing(True)

x = sp.Symbol("x")
f = (x**3)*sp.DiracDelta(x - 2)
```

*Attempt 1*

```
f.integrate((x, 0, 3))
# 8
```

*Attempt 2*

```
g = sp.Integral(f, (x, 0, 3))
g
```

[image]

```
g.evalf()
# 0
```

Comment: `g.doit()` also returns 8.

Comment: issue opened at https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/17552